# Left Join Is Returning One value for entire column

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am doing a left join on another table in the subquery and the commission column I want to return from the left join is only bringing one value for the entire commission column which is wrong (see first query result below). Now if I do the left join outside of table A (query 2) then I get the desired results (see second result set). The question is why isn't the left join working within table A in the first query.

I have tried left joining outside of subquery/table A (query 2) and it it works fine but I want to learn why isn't the left join working within the table A.

The query (query 1) is below which is giving the duplicate values in the commission column

```
Position_A1 table

Sector      Short_Side
------------------------
Engineering  -2
Financial    -5
Industry     -10
Corporate    -36    
Energy       -52
Financial    -26

Order table

Sector      Commission
------------------------
Engineering  10
Financial    100
Industry     36
Corporate    91 
Energy       10
Financial   25
```

Query 1

```
SELECT *   
FROM
(SELECT POS.SECTOR, 
  SUM(ABS(POS.SHORT_SIDE)) AS Short_Expo,       
  COM.COMMISSION
FROM Position_A1 POS

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SECTOR, sum(COMMISSION) AS COMMISSION
            FROM ORDER
            WHERE TRADE_DATE = TO_DATE('2019-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
            GROUP BY SECTOR 
            )COM
            ON POS.SECTOR = COM.SECTOR 

WHERE TRADE_DATE = TO_DATE('2019-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY SECTOR ) A
```

However, if I try the below, I get the correct results in the commission column.

Query 2

```
SELECT A.*, COM.COMMISSION   
FROM
(SELECT POS.SECTOR, 
  SUM(ABS(POS.SHORT_SIDE)) AS Short_Expo       
FROM Position_A1 POS

WHERE TRADE_DATE = TO_DATE('2019-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY SECTOR ) A

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SECTOR, sum(COMMISSION) AS COMMISSION
            FROM ORDER
            WHERE TRADE_DATE = TO_DATE('2019-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
            GROUP BY SECTOR 
            )COM
            ON POS.SECTOR = COM.SECTOR
```

As per the first query the result I get is:

```
Sector      Short_Expo      Commission
Energy      256             125
Industry    236             125
Financial   125             125
```

As per the second query the result I get (which is correct) is:

```
Sector      Short_Expo      Commission
Energy      256             128
Industry    236             325
Financial   125             186
```

The question is why isn't query one giving the ideal result whereas query 2. What am I doing wrong in the first query that is resulting in duplicate commission?

Using the first it seems that the commission for only one sector (Financial) is being returned for all sectors.

Comment: It's difficult to follow what you're intending to happen and what's actually happening. When asking a question, bear in mind that nobody else can run these queries. It'll help if you remove everything not directly relevant to the question from your queries (`trade date`? `rating`? `c_type`?); also, you'll want to include some representative sample data showing your input, what you're actually getting, and what you're expecting to get.

Comment: hi, apologies, i have made changes, i hope this helps

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your queries. In your first query, grouping by sector first in a subquery, then doing the same grouping again in the outer query is very strange, but there could be cases where it's valid. We can't really answer why you're not getting the results you expect unless you show what your data-model looks like. What's in `Position_A1`? What's in `ORDER`? In any case, your second query looks much cleaner than your first. If that's showing the results you expect, what's the issue?

Comment: Is your first query really the one you used? I would expect it to error, since your com.commission column isn't in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, the `WHERE` clause in the outer query (`WHERE TRADE_DATE = TO_DATE('2019-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`) is turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` because the non-matching values are `NULL` and they don't match.

The normal solution is to include filtering on subsequent tables in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Gordon, the where clause in the COM table or table A?

Comment: @Ali_M . . . I clarified.